# White window when exporting Eclipse project to jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I exported my project, but when I opened the .jar file it was just a white window.
Here are some screenshots with the build path:

[Order and Export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PC3S.png)

[Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ozkvo.png)

When I run the game inside Eclipse everythink works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is there a source folder in libraries, do you use a source folder from a different project or are you adding it just to try and see if it works?

You only said that a white window shows and nothing else happens after, maybe the program was starting to run but failed mid execution. The only way to know the cause is to run it on cmd with the command: **java -jar AppName.jar**

Comment: Yeah, when I was exporting it I had to put the jar in a same folder with the resources. I'm a beginner and I don't know very much about exporting.

Comment: that's why i asked to know if it was a folder from a different project which could require adding in the proper location but if you're exporting a project and that src folder we see is the projects src folder then I see no reason why you would need to do it, if that is the case I would advise you to return the build path to default and run the command I mentioned earlier, if there's something wrong with the app, either it is files not being found or certain files not being accessed, the command in cmd will give you that information.